# how to apply format of an adiacent row in Excel when the cell is empty

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting

I have a row containing, let's say, the following values:

> 0, empty, empty, 1, empty, 0, 1

I want to apply a conditional formatting so that:

- cell 0: background is RED
- cell 1: background is GREEN
- cell empty: background is equal to the previous cell background

the result should be:

> RED, RED, RED, GREEN, GREEN, RED, GREEN

The question is: using conditional formatting, how to apply to a cell the format of a previous cell ?

thank you in advance for any comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a formula for this formatting:

- select the range you want to format
- go to home - conditional formatting - new rule - use a formula to decide which cells to format
- for formula field enter this:
  `=INDEX($A$1:A1,MAX(IF($A$1:A1<>"",COLUMN($A$1:A1),"")))=1`
- set formatting for cells with `1`
- the rule for cells with `0`, will be similar, just the end is different:
  `=INDEX($A$1:A1,MAX(IF($A$1:A1<>"",COLUMN($A$1:A1),"")))=0`

[image]

Comment: Thank you Máté, the solution effectively solves the question posted. Moreover your approach 'evaluate true if 1 or empty' is interesting and I'm wondering if it is possible to apply it to a real case, in which I have a pivottable with 'expandable' cells

Comment: I don't really understand your example with the pivottable. Maybe you can ask it a new question and add some sample data.

Comment: I've solved my problem using pivotable and your formula, and I prepared a detailed post of the solution. Unfortunately I cannot publish it because it contain images and I have not enought reputation for that (I need 10 I have 3). If you think my question is interesting, please upvote this post so that I earn the missing points and can publish the solution. thank you RV

Comment: @RobertoVanoli you can still post your solution, please upload your pictures to imgur and include their link in your answer, somebody with enough reputation will include them for you.

Comment: I have posted a sample of using your formula with a pivotable here http://superuser.com/questions/1121432/how-to-apply-conditional-formatting-of-an-adiacent-row-in-a-pivotable-when-the-c